# Retrieving count of likes is wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to retrieve count of likes fo each url like "http://some.url/gallery/?photo={n}", but I get count of likes for page "http://some.url/gallery/". So, facebook does not account GET parameter, when I trying to get count of 'likes'.

Comment: Are you url encoding the url when you send it to the api?

Comment: Sure, I've tested it in [explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) also.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your page in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). My bet is you've got code on your page that defines `http://some.url/gallery/` as the canonical url.

Facebook only counts likes for canonical urls. You'll need to change your code so each unique page, including all the appropriate `GET` parameters, is canonical.

Comment: I've tested it in the debugger, but all links are correct. I guess that this error is associated with different domains. My page is located on subdomain, but canonical url is on primary domain. Is it possible?

Comment: If the debugger shows a different canonical url, then that is the page that the likes are counting on.